# How to add mean separation letters above bars in a vertical facet?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I'm trying to make a figure containing three bar plots vertically. I can do it successfully using Facets in ggplot2 but was wondering how I can add the mean separation letters above each bar for the respective plot. Data is separated by harvest in the facet (1-3). Please find sample data below, followed by code for the facet, and then final code I created for just one of the harvest in which I was successful in adding separation letters. Thank you:

```
Rootstock   Harvest N   Length.cm.  sd  se  ci  Lower   Upper
1   A   1   8   76.51075    36.00585368 12.72999165 30.10164697 63.78075835 89.24074165
2   A   2   8   160.9014    59.41736724 21.00721165 49.67416212 139.8941884 181.9086116
3   A   3   8   325.2713625 117.812772  41.653105   98.49394223 283.6182575 366.9244675
4   B   1   8   71.09765    38.1718855  13.49579954 31.91249489 57.60185046 84.59344954
5   B   2   8   142.1246375 67.33487775 23.80647433 56.29336655 118.3181632 165.9311118
6   B   3   8   336.24105   115.3372241 40.77786664 96.42433239 295.4631834 377.0189166
7   C   1   8   46.3798 25.53625659 9.028430101 21.34884477 37.3513699  55.4082301
8   C   2   8   118.4134875 65.35360032 23.10598698 54.63697717 95.30750052 141.5194745
9   C   3   8   281.5792375 117.049729  41.38332856 97.85602232 240.1959089 322.9625661
10  D   1   7   86.62565714 37.50832694 14.17681503 34.6894167  72.44884212 100.8024722
11  D   2   6   120.86055   48.8806253  19.95543172 51.2970703  100.9051183 140.8159817
12  D   3   8   274.203525  86.86426453 30.71115524 72.62034249 243.4923698 304.9146802
13  E   1   8   57.2146875  26.41120188 9.337769974 22.08031734 47.87691753 66.55245747
14  E   2   8   120.2972875 45.39353788 16.04903923 37.94994738 104.2482483 136.3463267
15  E   3   8   333.678325  103.5042683 36.594285   86.53173379 297.08404   370.27261
16  F   1   8   81.166225   37.18034784 13.14523804 31.08354867 68.02098696 94.31146304
17  F   2   8   161.96095   71.60747702 25.31706629 59.86534893 136.6438837 187.2780163
 18 F   3   7   331.6084286 195.9165314 74.04948854 181.1925711 257.55894   405.6579171
19  G   1   8   68.743  44.9696775  15.89918195 37.59559123 52.84381805 84.64218195
 20 G   2   8   142.6372625 80.95226642 28.62094827 67.67778838 114.0163142 171.2582108
21  G   3   8   362.7983625 143.4288665 50.70976205 119.9095331 312.0886004 413.5081246
22  H   1   8   55.2445625  31.35474448 11.08557622 26.21322238 44.15898628 66.33013872
 23 H   2   8   125.48165   97.10938809 34.33335342 81.18548013 91.14829658 159.8150034
 24 H   3   8   402.004975  176.9811861 62.57229841 147.9599743 339.4326766 464.5772734
25  I   1   7   63.47242857 30.17893187 11.40656408 27.91085683 52.06586449 74.87899265
26  I   2   8   167.4317875 76.30008692 26.97615443 63.78846899 140.4556331 194.4079419
27  I   3   8   357.2169125 108.6952357 38.42956911 90.8714911  318.7873434 395.6464816
28  J   1   8   65.6122875  29.5111406  10.43376382 24.67193096 55.17852368 76.04605132
29  J   2   8   126.4079875 66.06781069 23.35849848 55.23407198 103.049489  149.766486
30  J   3   8   502.1878625 140.3556285 49.62320833 117.3402419 452.5646542 551.8110708
31  K   1   8   57.3303625  27.86618278 9.852183406 23.29671181 47.47817909 67.18254591
32  K   2   8   106.203025  52.69142229 18.629231   44.05113142 87.573794   124.832256
33  K   3   7   348.9141    166.4786335 62.92300897 153.9670564 285.991091  411.837109
34  L   1   8   54.4373375  32.89032536 11.62848605 27.49700012 42.80885145 66.06582355
35  L   2   8   173.801975  114.7929316 40.58543019 95.9692925  133.2165448 214.3874052
36  L   3   8   427.5621    141.5160672 50.03348538 118.3103929 377.5286146 477.5955854
37  N   1   8   53.19965    18.75340803 6.630330993 15.67824146 46.56931901 59.82998099
 38 N   2   8   102.83935   49.66950295 17.56082118 41.52474363 85.27852882 120.4001712
39  N   3   8   361.586525  123.0931912 43.52001511 102.9084831 318.0665099 405.1065401
40  M   1   8   90.71195    45.58629605 16.11718953 38.11109723 74.59476047 106.8291395
41  M   2   8   201.219475  90.14563026 31.87129323 75.36363289 169.3481818 233.0907682
42  M   3   8   521.6052875 144.9878341 51.26094033 121.2128627 470.3443472 572.8662278
43  O   1   8   72.572875   37.76520057 13.35201471 31.57249778 59.22086029 85.92488971
44  O   2   8   181.783975  97.67988452 34.53505436 81.66242708 147.2489206 216.3190294
45  O   3   8   415.6914625 179.8261041 63.57812883 150.3383853 352.1133337 479.2695913
46  P   1   8   58.817375   22.82069356 8.068333583 19.07857726 50.74904142 66.88570858
47  P   2   8   131.3006875 67.37113752 23.8192941  56.32368048 107.4813934 155.1199816
48  P   3   8   286.8072625 49.36617664 17.45357913 41.27115649 269.3536834 304.2608416
49  Q   1   8   76.4929625  50.22446933 17.75703142 41.98870713 58.73593108 94.24999392
50  Q   2   8   174.730975  111.6447534 39.47238111 93.33734965 135.2585939 214.2033561
51  Q   3   8   363.4492125 169.6025304 59.96354967 141.7912638 303.4856628 423.4127622
52  R   1   8   72.9998875  24.48056866 8.655188055 20.46626758 64.34469945 81.65507555
53  R   2   8   172.1736375 97.8407617  34.59193304 81.79692377 137.5817045 206.7655705
54  R   3   8   453.68845   177.718465  62.83296587 148.5763549 390.8554841 516.5214159
```

Code with Facet:

```
library(ggplot2)
AllHarvest<-summarySE(CombinedwinrhizoSigmaPlot, measurevar="Length.cm.", groupvars=c("Rootstock","Harvest"))
AllHarvest$Lower <- AllHarvest$Length.cm. - AllHarvest$se
AllHarvest$Upper <- AllHarvest$Length.cm. + AllHarvest$se

AllHplot<-ggplot(AllHarvest,aes(x=Rootstock, y=Length.cm., fill=Rootstock)) + ylim(0,600) + geom_bar(colour = "black", stat="identity", width = 0.7, fill = "#4DAF4A") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, width = 0.2), size=0.5, color = "black")
AllHplot + facet_grid(Harvest ~ .)
```

Code for Harvest #3 including mean separation letters above bars:

```
Harvest3 <- AllHarvest[which(Harvest =="3"),]
Harvest3summary <- summarySE(Harvest3, measurevar="Length.cm.", groupvars=c("Rootstock"))

offset.v = -8     # offsets for mean letters
offset.h = 0.4

 Harvest3summary$Lower <- Harvest3summary$Length.cm. - Harvest3summary$se
 Harvest3summary$Upper <- Harvest3summary$Length.cm. + Harvest3summary$se
 Harvest3plot <- ggplot(Harvest3summary,aes(x=Rootstock, y=Length.cm., fill=Rootstock)) + ylim(0,600) +
  geom_bar(colour = "black", stat="identity", width = 0.7, fill = "#4DAF4A") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, width = 0.2), size=0.5, color = "black") +
   geom_text(aes(label=c("CDE", "CDE", "DE", "DE","CDE","E","BCDE","ABCDE","ABCDE","AB","CDE", "ABC", "ABCDE","A","ABCD","CDE","BCDE","ABC"), size = 8, hjust=offset.h, vjust=offset.v)) +              
   labs(x = "", y = expression(Total~Root~Length~(cm)))  +     theme(legend.position = "none") +
  ## ggtitle("Main title")  +
   theme(
plot.title = element_text(size = rel(1.5), 
                          face = "bold", vjust = 1.5),
axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
axis.title.y = element_text(vjust= 1.8, size=14),
axis.text.y=element_text(size=12),
axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5),
axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1.1,vjust=1.05, size=14, colour="black"))
 panel.border = element_rect(colour="black")
```

Comment: Any help or suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking around a bit I was able to answer my own question through trial and error. I am adding code for those who may want to use it in the future - this is especially helpful for journal figures where mean separation letters are needed. A note - when using `geom_text` you add your separation letters as one long string for all graphs in the facet, so make sure you have them ordered correctly:

```
AllHplot<-ggplot(AllHarvest,aes(x=Rootstock, y=Length.cm., fill=Rootstock)) + coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0,650)) + geom_blank()+ theme_bw() + geom_bar(colour = "black", stat="identity", width = 0.7, fill = "black") + geom_errorbar(aes(ymax=Upper, ymin=Lower, width = 0.2), size=0.5, color = "black")+              
labs(x = "", y = expression(paste(Total~Root~Length~(cm)))) + scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0,0)) +
theme(
    axis.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", vjust= 1.8, size=14),
    axis.text.y=element_text(size=12, colour="black"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(vjust= -0.5),
    panel.grid.major=element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor=element_blank(),
    axis.text.x  = element_text(angle=60, hjust=1.1, vjust=1.05, size=14, colour="black"),
    strip.background = element_blank(), 
    strip.text = element_blank())+ geom_text(aes(label=c("CDE", "CDE", "DE", "DE","CDE","E","BCDE","ABCDE","ABCDE","AB","CDE", "ABC", "ABCDE","A","ABCD","CDE","BCDE","ABC", "ABC", "ABCDEF", "CDEF", "BCDEF","BCDEF","ABC","BCDEF","EF","ABC","CDEF","DEF", "ABCD", "F","A","AB","BCDEF","ABCDE","ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "D", "AB","BCD","AB","ABCD","CD","ABCD","ABCD","BCD", "CD", "BCD","A","ABC","ABCD","ABC","ABC"),  hjust=offset.h, vjust=offset.v)) + facet_grid(Harvest ~ .,as.table=F)
```